# Installing modules

Tags: python

I'm new to programming in Python. I can't figure out how to install a library called Requests. I followed a youtube instructional video, and it seems to be able to import the module in command prompt, but not from the IDLE, which I would prefer to use.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `pip install requests`

Comment: If the command-line REPL can see the module and IDLE can't, maybe they're running different installs of Python. Try running `import sys; print(sys.version)` in both of them to confirm that they're the same.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I must have been running the IDLE from another version of Python that I downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

To install and manage python modules use `pip` , as it would show you the list of modules warn you at times and also help you to safely remove the python module.

Install pip instructions

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-dev` or [Go to the Link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Mac OS X: `brew install python`

You can use pip to install the modules like

`pip install django` (this would install django module and its dependencies into your system globally)
`pip uninstall django` (this would uninstall django module from your system)
`pip freeze` (would list all the modules install in the system

Using a Virtualenv and Virtualenvwrapper would make your development flow even more easy.

install virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper.

Installation Instructions of Virtualenv and Virtualenvwrapper

Ubuntu:[Click Here](http://t.order.objects.filter(Q(order_user_detail__user__user_facebook_id=user_detail[0]['user_facebook_id'])&Q(order_visibility=True)&~(Q(order_status=14)%7CQ(r_order_status=20))).values('order_parent_id','order_comment'%20).distinct('order_parent_id'))

Mac OS X: [Click Here](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-mac-os-x/)

Windows: [Refer this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615968/installing-virtualenvwrapper-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest installing virtualenv. Then in a virtual environment, install the required library (Requests) in your case using `pip install requests`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using the IDLE from another version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem previously try to install **urlib3** then go for requests. Also use it using **python3**.
.