# Use virtualenvwrapper in git bash shells like MINGW64 or Cygwin on Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-10, cygwin, mingw-w64, virtualenvwrapper

Since I'd been using Linux for almost 10 years, the fact that I had to switch to Windows 10 created several difficulties as for my common workflow using *python, pyenv, virtualenvwrapper and bash UNIX shell*.

Therefore, I've installed the following shells:

1. MINGW64 (git shell) via chocolatey package manager in PowerShell: `choco install git`
2. Cygwin: https://www.cygwin.com/
3. Ubuntu (WSL) from the [Windows app store](https://ubuntu.com/wsl)

Next, I wanted to set up my favorite virtual environment manager for python called [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
This resulted to be quite difficult and I ended up installing several versions to find out what eventually works (following commands executed in `PowerShell` after having installed `python3.9.x` via [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) in PowerShell):

1. pip install virtualenvwrapper ([pypi.org-page](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper/))
2. pip install virtualenvwrapper-win ([pypi.org-page](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/))
3. Cloning the virtualenvwrapper for PowerShell repo ([GitHub-page](https://github.com/regisf/virtualenvwrapper-powershell), [installation instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67104915/12298276))

While the 3rd option seems to work in `PowerShell`, it is a rather reduced version of the real `virtualenvwrapper` and I'd like to be able to use it in one of my several *git/bash/UNIX* shells.
Yet, when typing in any of the [virtualenvwrapper commands](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html) in `MINGW64` or `Cygwin` shells, it just returns in both of these shells:

```
username@... MINGW64 /
$ virtualenvwrapper
bash: virtualenvwrapper: command not found
```

On the other hand, when I try to install `virtualenvwrapper` again within these shells via `pip`, it states that it's already been installed.
I assume there's something wrong with the `PATH`s, but maybe it's even some other issue I haven't thought of.